# Why does my server suddenly restart?

Tags: vmware-esxi, server-crashes, hypervisor

I have a VMWare ESXI Hypervisor and its been working fine for the past 4-5 months but suddenly it's started randomly crashing after what seems to be under load.

There are 2 VM's on this hypervisor one UbuntuServer and Windows Server 2008

The windows server 2008 only runs a VPN and is rarely logged into.
The Ubuntu runs a Nginx Webserver MySql Server 2x Agar Server and 1x Minecraft Server.

Recently 3-8 hours after starting the Minecraft Server the whole machine reboots.

It is water cooled and air cooled with an Intel i7 CPU Quad Core 3.4 Ghz.
I may have a suspicion that the boot drive for ESXI could be full, would this cause a restart such as?
Any idea what could be causing this problem?

Dying CPU
Power Supply
Overheating?

Is there anyway to narrow down the cause?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could start by adding monitoring to your server. ESXI has a log file that you can analyze, the IPMI board of the server surely has one as well.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I am sorry but I am relatively new to these acronyms. What is the IPMI board?

Comment: The remote management console of your server. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Platform_Management_Interface

Comment: right so like the ESXI client interface.. Yeah I need to have a proper look. I access the server remotely via VPN running on a guest machine so settings were configured to autmatically boot all guest VMs but this config did not save so I wonder if the disk is full or something. I get an error every hour or so saying something like "failed to save ha-datacenter" I cant remember currently because I have not access to the server this moment.